# how to serialize svg so it can fit into a cookie

Tags: php, serialization, cookies, image-processing, svg

I need to serialize an svg image so that it can be stored into a cookie.

I need to set the cookie over, and then unserialize the svg image when they return.

So basically my problems comes down to serializing svg into something that can be stored in a cookie. How can I do this?

I know there are serialize() and unserialize() in php, but serialize takes in a mixed value and i'm not sure that svg would fall into that category.

I researched mixed values a bit and it looks like it can take in `struct`, `array`s, `int`, etc, but not svg. If I'm wrong about this please tell me because using serialize and unserialize would make things much easier.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using a cookie to store images you are probably doing something very wrong.

Comment: well actually that is very possible with serialization. you can serialize svg to string and store the string in a cookie. then get the string from the cookie and unserialize it to svg. i can do that part fine. my only issue is commanding when it stores the image. basically anytime the svg changes, i want to be able to save it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Scalable Vector Graphics are just XML and therefore simply text (usually UTF-8 encoded, although it should be identical to ASCII unless you explicitly add any non-ASCII characters). Yet an SVG string will contain special characters which are not allowed in a cookie, so you need to escape these (semi-colon, comma and space should be escaped, if i remember correctly, you could just use the urlencode function from php). That's all it takes from the aspect of serialization. The big problem might be the size limit: a cookie must not be longer than 4096 characters, including the length of the name. For more complicated SVGs this might be too little.

Comment: what do you mean escape and how do i use semi-colon to escape?

Comment: There are some characters that have a special meaning. If you want to use these, you have to somehow "hide" them from being interpreted in a special way. Basically all you have to do is `$cookie_value = urlencode($svgstring);`, if I remember correctly. This will for example replace ` ` (space) by `%20` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding). Later you can use `$svgstring=urldecode($cookie_value);` when you get the cookie value from the user.

Comment: alite i understand that, but my issue now is this. i have an <svg> and a <g> inside the <svg>. my problem is i want to save the svg into a cookie whenever my svg changes. basically i made the svg editable. so whenever there are changes, aka onchange, i would be able to save it to the cookie. but <svg> and <g> do not have an onchange event (correct me if im wrong). so what do i do about this?

Comment: <svg>
  <g>
    <image x=7 y=8 id=a>
    <text id=b>
    ...
  <g>
<svg>

some code down here that refers to the id a and b and changes it.

basically thats the structure i have right now. the only issue is i want to use the onchange javascript attribute but these tags dont have it.

Comment: Well, you're the one who changes them, so why should there be an event about that? What you might try to do is encapsulating these in an object with methods. That way you can call functions whenever an object is manipulated by you. I doubt though, that there isn't a much, much better approach to what you want to do than the one you're currently trying.